# JavaScript - Front-end MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django

### My actual question here:

I'm wondering if ([beargrylls.com](http://www.beargrylls.com/)) uses Django or it's packages. Or some other framework. Or a custom framework? Also, if you take a look at the website ([beargrylls.com](http://www.beargrylls.com/)), you can see that it uses a lot of paralax scrolling, sliders and cool animations. Is this custom-made or is this another framework/plugin/whatever?

If found an awesome website ([beargrylls.com](http://www.beargrylls.com/)) on [awwwards.com](https://www.awwwards.com/). I'm familiar with the MVC model that Laravel uses. So I know the basics. But I found out that ([beargrylls.com](http://www.beargrylls.com/)) uses some kind of routing inside it's scripts!?

What I also found remarkanble is that the script(s) and the entite css of the website is loaded in inline HTML. So there are no HTTP requests, no files to load except the images

**Which framework/plugin compiles this?**

**Example:**

```
  , Route = function t() {
    classCallCheck(this, t);
    var e = new Router({
        xhr: !0
    });
    e.get("/", HomeController),
    e.get("/about", AboutController),
    e.get("/television", TelevisionController),
    e.get("/live", LiveController),
    e.get("/experiences", ExperiencesController),
    e.get("/socialwall", SocialwallController),
    e.get("/adventurers", AdventurersController),
    e.get("/termsofuse", TermsofuseController),
    e.get("/faqs", FaqsController),
    e.get("/signup", SignupController),
    e.error(ErrorController),
    e.run()
}
  , App = function t() {
    classCallCheck(this, t),
    Support.init(),
    index.TopWhenRefresh(),
    new Route
};
new App;
```

Another example that boosted my suspisions can be found inside it's createClass function or class. Where it assumably creates classes.

```
this.backgroundWrap = index.Geb.id("h-header-background-wrap"),
this.centerWrap = index.Geb.id("h-header-center-wrap"),
this.foregroundWrap = index.Geb.id("h-header-foreground-wrap"),
this.titleWrap = index.Geb.id("h-header-title-wrap"),
this.introTxt = index.Geb.id("h-intro-txt"),
this.introLine = index.Geb.id("h-intro-line"),
this.introVideo = index.Geb.id("h-intro-video"),
this.introScroll = index.Geb.id("h-intro-scroll"),
this.nav = index.Geb.class("nav")[0],
this.progress = index.Geb.id("h-intro-progress"),
this.scrollLineWrap = index.Geb.id("h-header-scroll-line-wrap"),
this.scrollTxtWrap = index.Geb.id("h-header-scroll-txt-wrap"),
this.stickyBurger = index.Geb.id("sticky-burger"),
```

So it seems to me that almost this entire website (routing, element classes and more) is created trough this script. I even see some mailchimp tags here.

---

I looked into the Django framework because of some of the links to media folders like `/static/`.

Comment: So, what website were you looking at, again?

Comment: Which framework/plugin compiles this? If this even a framework/plugin? What is this

Comment: @Cerbrus it's created with Vue.js (https://vuejs.org/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Penryn-starter

A starter kit for web development.

1. Docker
2. Browsersync
3. PHP 7.1.8
4. PostCSS
5. Css Nano
6. ES2015
7. ESLint
8. Rollup
9. Uglify JS 3
10. Skylake

### https://github.com/ariiiman/penryn-starter

---

### Skylake:

It's a Light JavaScript library named **Skylake**:

https://github.com/ariiiman/skylake

**example:**

```
const animation = new S.Merom('.element', '3dy', 0, 100, 1000, 'Power4InOut')
animation.play()
animation.reverse()
```

Similar functions can also be found in the Sources tab of the Google Devtools on [beargrylls.com](http://www.beargrylls.com/):

```
this.tlImg.from(this.background, "3dy", 10, 0, 2e3, "ExpoOut")
```

Also, in the script can skylake be found litterally:

```
scroll: {
    throttle: !0,
    skylake: "Scroll"
},
```

---

But I'm not quite sure what this actually does. I can't explain the routing class or anything of that sort. But it defenitely uses this Skylake library.

---

The same structure of code can be found on these websites: https://www.aristidebenoist.com/ (author of Skylake) and on http://www.jennyjohannesson.com/

though I do not think that these websites are using Skylake. Or just use other variables or something. But this:

```
              , App = function e() {
                classCallCheck(this, e),
                Support.init(),
                index.TopWhenRefresh(),
                new Router({
                    xhr: !0
                })
            };
            !function(e) {
                new App
            }();
        }
        )();
```

is exactly the same as on beargrylls.com

also the almost exact same Route class can be found on http://www.jennyjohannesson.com/

Comment: So, why isn't there a `Vue` global variable accessible from the console?

Comment: you tell me, please

Comment: Okay, let's puit it differently: What do you base this on? HTML like that can be from multiple different libraries. Where did you see the `new Vue({`? You're answering your own question with a guess.

Comment: @Cerbrus so you think this is perhaps custom made?

Comment: @Cerbrus I thought I had it right: Vue.js. Apparently that's not the case. But when someone actually thinks he/she knows, he/she can post an answer of it, though. Much more helpful than no answers at all. I might actually learn from wrong answers as well. (like mine here, the only answer on this page at the moment). I'm just eager to learn and to know more about webdevelopment, so if you or someone else has an alternative (like Vue.js), feel free to comment

Comment: At least I know found out that this website is using Merom.js! https://github.com/ariiiman/skylake

Comment: ... Based on what did you determine this? And wouldn't you update the answer then?

Comment: @Cerbus just did, maybe this is useful

Comment: @Cerbrus it's the author's other repo: Penryn Starter (A starter kit for web development.) https://github.com/ariiiman/penryn-starter this includes his other repo: Skylake